# Determining Source and Destination IPs on same subnet (Python)

Tags: python, input, ip, ip-address, subnet

Write a program that queries the user a src IP address, a destination IP address and then a 32 bit subnet mask. All entered in dot decimal notation. The program will then determine if src and dst are on the same subnet. It will then print the mask and the two addresses in binary format (on separate rows, vertically aligned with each other) and indicate who the host should ARP for.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

src_ip = input("Please enter the Source IP Address: ")

dst_ip = input("Please enter the Destination IP Address: ")

sub_mask = input("Please enter the Subnet Mask: ")

#convert each to binary
base2_src = [format(int(x), '08b') for x in src_ip.split('.')]
base2_dst = [format(int(x), '08b') for x in dst_ip.split('.')]
base2_mask = [format(int(x), '08b') for x in sub_mask.split('.')]

#print out IP addresses in binary
print("Source IP: ", base2_src)
print("Destination IP: ", base2_dst)
print("Subnet Mask :", base2_mask)
```

So far I am able to take the input, convert it to binary and output it in a list. How do I determine if the source and destination entered are on the same subnet, with the subnet that the user entered? What should I be comparing the binary converted subnet mask to?

Answer (score 0):

Mask identifies the subnet to which IP address belongs by performing bitwise AND operation on the mask and the IP address. The result will be subnetwork address. So you can just do it for your source and destination and then compare the results.

Comment: So what you are saying is: 1) perform AND on src ip and subnet mask, store the result in a list 2) perform AND on dst ip and subnet mask, store result in a list 3) compare the two results together? But would a bitwise AND operand work on lists?

Comment: Nope. But why don`t you store them not as lists, but as binary number variables? That could be done by using python`s built-in function bin()

Comment: but what if it is a list of binary integers instead of strings?